# Opennyxl:как сделать перенос текста

Tags: python, excel, таблицы

У меня не влезает текст в ячейку excel из-за чего он просто обрезается ,а мне бы хотелось что-бы он переносился на другую строку в этой же ячейке. Как это можно сделать если я работаю с таблицами через библиотеку Opennyxl в python ?

Comment: Вот это смотрели? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215933/apply-wrap-text-to-all-cells-using-openpyxl>

Comment: @СергейКох. Да только она почему-то работает не так как задумается. Оно просто съедает часть  текста а не переносит его на другие строки.

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке openpyxl, чтобы установить перенос текста в ячейке, необходимо использовать атрибут wrap_text объекта ячейки. При установке этого атрибута в значение True, текст в ячейке будет автоматически переноситься на новую строку при достижении конца ячейки.

```
cell[0].alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
```